# How do I create a calendar icon that picks dates, but doesn't show the input in pure javascript/html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, calendar

My goal

[image: Calendar pops up when the calendar icon is pressed]

What is available

[image]

This is done using a simple calendar input.

```
<input type="date">
```

I have tried reducing the width of the input, but then it doesn't seem elegant as it deforms in different browsers. The previous images were on chrome. Below is how it appears in Mozilla.

[image]

I think I could specify the width for each browser. That however seems inelegant and convoluted.

Comment: Have a look to this blog https://dev.to/codeclown/styling-a-native-date-input-into-a-custom-no-library-datepicker-2in

Answer (score 2):

In [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=showPicker) you can use the `showPicker()` method of an `input[type=date]` element to make the widget appear.

So, with that in mind, you could move the `<input>` outside of a container with `overflow:hidden` and trigger the widget from a `click` event on another element.

Something like the snippet below *might* work, though I wouldn't really suggest using this in a public facing web app due to the limited support :

```js
let cal = document.querySelector('label.calendar');
let ci = document.querySelector('label.calendar input[type=date]');
cal.addEventListener('click', event => ci.showPicker());
```

```css
label.calendar {
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.calendar input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="calendar">
  <input type="date">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Instead, I would recommend you look into other (more mature) options like [Smart HTML Calendar](https://www.htmlelements.com/docs/calendar/) which is a [Custom HTML Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve is not possible to do in one solution for every browser because the "date" input type is rendered by the browser and every one of them has their own specification on how to render things. You could try to use a custom component or plugin that renders a calendar using javascript/CSS/HTML that is the only way to have a consistent look and feel across different browsers.